# Logging level under maven surefire

Tags: maven-2, junit, surefire

I'm unable to adjust java logging's logging level. I'm using maven surefire (mvn test), and trying to adjust from the default INFO to e.g. FINEST.

I have logging.properties file under **src/test/resources/logging.properties**

after compile, i see under target/test-classes, i see a logging.properties file with the intended config:

**java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level=FINEST**

**javax.enterprise.system.container.ejb.level=FINE**

...

however the console output from glassfish only have INFO / SEVERE level messages.

Where did I go wrong? or is this another pain in the butt thing with maven?

Comment: I'm a bit confused here. How does glassfish fit into this? I think it's likely you are getting confused between glassfish's logging and the maven unit test logging. What framework is the maven build using for logging?

Comment: i'm debugging a unit test that uses the Embedded container in glassfish v3. according to: http://forums.java.net/jive/thread.jspa?messageID=395759, under reply by 'Marina Vatkina', thats the key to output FINE messages for the EJB container... I guess my question is is my setup correct for java util logging? Or is there extra configuration needed? - not just for this particular instance, but lets say I have a class com.something.Main, and i want to output FINEST messages for it...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to specifiy your handlers in the logging file

```
handlers = java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler, java.util.logging.FileHandler
```

then it should work

Comment: which file? and what about a log4j.xml file syntax?

Answer (score 19):

I tried setting `java.util.logging.config.file` in the `MAVEN_OPTS` environment variable, which does not work but finally got it working by putting that system property in the `pom.xml` (and of course creating an appropriate `logging.properties` in `src/test/resources`):

```
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
           <systemProperties>
             <property> 
               <name>java.util.logging.config.file</name>
               <value>src/test/resources/logging.properties</value>
             </property>
           </systemProperties>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

Comment: Setting `-Djava.util.logging.config.file` on the maven command line did not work for me, but this did.

Comment: Because surefire plugin do not propogate all system properties you passed to maven one the command line to actual unit test executor

Answer (score 3):

try

```
${build.testOutputDirectory}/logging.properties
```

Also, I specify this stuff on the command line with surfire-args.

```
<argLine>${surefire.argLine} ${argLine} -Djava.util.logging.config.file=${build.testOutputDirectory}/logging.properties</argLine>
```

Answer (score 2):

I was looking at this exact issue, but did not want a project configuration (pom.xml) file change for every time I need specific logging on a test.

The -D property works from maven command line.

Thus you can select the logging configuration file from the command line:

```
mvn -Djava.util.logging.config.file=`enter filename here` test
```

If you are using the generic level denominator `.level=FINEST` be aware that 3rd party logging will also appear at that level.

To disable or set the maven or 3rd party logging to a specific level use explicit log level selection for those classes in the selected log configuration file.

I have a lot of log lines from com.google.inject.....

```
aug 08, 2014 12:14:33 PM com.google.inject.internal.util.$Stopwatch resetAndLog
FINE: Instance member validation: 3ms
aug 08, 2014 12:14:33 PM com.google.inject.internal.util.$Stopwatch resetAndLog
FINE: Provider verification: 1ms
aug 08, 2014 12:14:33 PM com.google.inject.internal.util.$Stopwatch resetAndLog
FINE: Static member injection: 1ms
```

So I add:

```
com.google.inject.level=INFO
```

to the file. Remember that the level setting is recursive to all subclasses. Thus `com.level=NONE` will disable all logging for all loggers from the `com` domain.

Combining this with the test select feature `-Dtest=...` in the surefire plugin described [here](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/single-test.html) is very good for isolating bugs and errors.