# Where should I put logging.properties file for java.util.logging in web application (maven project)?

Tags: java, web-applications, maven, java.util.logging

I want to logging to file and set it in properties file, because default logger.info() output goes to console and in web application there is no console in my case.

Answer (score 19):

As Navi says... it goes in  `src/main/resources`

Just to clarify this subject... the logging.properties **must** go in `WEB-INF/classes` directory.
If you are using some kind of framework for organizing your project, you must find out where to place the file in order to stay in `WEB-INF/classes`
If you are using maven to organize the web app, you must know that everything that lies in `src/main/resources` goes to `WEB-INF/classes.`

Answer (score 11):

you should put in src/main/resources

Comment: This is the correct answer to the question and I've up-voted it as such.  However, *is it a good practice to include properties* files like this in the .jar/.war/.ear/etc... for an application?  Shouldn't the application provide a sample configuration (or at most a default one) and allow the installer to configure the logging on their system however they like?  I realize this is an open ended question, so what's the accepted best practice? (assuming there is one)

Comment: and where and what should I place instead of this: java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=mylogging.properties ? in tomcat 6

Comment: I see that by default (no own logging.properties) tomcat6 send default java.util.logging log.info() to file /var/log/tomcat6/catalina-(date)-.log This must be enough for me now, later I'll read this http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/logging.html#Using_java.util.logging_%28default%29

Comment: AFAIK the logging.properties file won't be read from the classpath, so just putting it into src/main/resources won't do.

Answer (score 0):

This is the first place I found when I was trying to figure out where my logging.properties file needed to go while testing.

**TL;DR**:  `src/test/resources`

#### Deploy to Tomcat

When running as a web application, as [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4714767/where-should-i-put-logging-properties-file-for-java-util-logging-in-web-applicat#comment5206648_4714875) suggests, I don't need to deploy a logging.properties file to `src/main/resources` (although that probably would have fixed my immediate problem).  My container already has one.  For Tomcat, that location is `$CATALINA_HOME/conf/logging.properties`.  If you are running Tomcat from Eclipse, you can set that in launch configuration, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30094364/6660678).

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16772478/6660678) talks about setting up different logging properties per application, which is what putting the file in `src/main/resources` does.

This section is the answer to the poster's question.  The rest of this is the answer to my similar but different problem.

#### Debugging tests

The actual problem that I was having was that my `java.util.logging` stopped showing the class name and method name after I added an SLF4J-using jar to my project and was trying to debug my unit tests.  I had to add `org.slf4j:slf4j-jdk14` to my POM in Provided scope so that my tests would run at all.  But then they didn't have class and method names.  Configuring the logging.properties file to match the one for Tomcat but with different [handlers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3999908/6660678) fixed that after I added some [Surefire configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12276898/6660678):

```
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
       <systemProperties>
         <property> 
           <name>java.util.logging.config.file</name>
           <value>src/test/resources/logging.properties</value>
         </property>
         <property>
           <name>java.util.logging.manager</name>
           <value>org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager</value>
         </property>
       </systemProperties>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

And my logs once again were showing all the information even when running tests from Maven.

#### Summary

If you want to set how your regular application is logging, then `src/main/resources` may be the right place.  But I wanted to change how my tests were logging, so I used `src/test/resources` instead.  Since Tomcat's launch configuration doesn't run under typical unit tests, I had to add some configuration to Surefire to serve the same purpose.  The logging.properties outside Tomcat does not use any Catalina jars, so I switched it to use different handlers.

Answer (score -6):

If you are using Tomcat, then you should log to `$CATALINA_HOME/logs/myapp/myapp.log`.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @the-elite-gentleman I'll let the OP be the judge of that. As far as I can tell, the OP wants to know where to log to, since he can't log to console in a webapp. I will happily delete/edit if I misunderstood the question.