# How do I set the java.util.logging log level in maven (for Jenkins plugin (JenkinsRule) tests)

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, java.util.logging

I'm writing a Jenkins plugin, and testing it using `mvn verify` and `JenkinsRule`.  So far so good, but I'd like to be able to quieten the output; it's pages per test.  What kind of config file do I use, and where do I put it?

I've tried a suitable log4j.properties (and just to be sure, a logging.properties) in src/test/resources (and thus target/test-classes); I've tried putting them in target/jenkins-for-test/WEB-INF/classes, that didn't help either.

In case it jogs anyone's memory, the output I'm trying to suppress are things like

```
Feb 08, 2014 2:26:40 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Started initialization
Feb 08, 2014 2:26:40 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Listed all plugins
```

and

```
Feb 08, 2014 2:26:44 PM hudson.PluginWrapper stop
INFO: Stopping javadoc
Feb 08, 2014 2:26:44 PM hudson.PluginWrapper stop
INFO: Stopping maven-plugin
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check this thread out : [Logging level under maven surefire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939072/logging-level-under-maven-surefire)

There are a couple of things you can try.  First, specify handlers in your logging.properties file by adding this line:

```
handlers = java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler, java.util.logging.FileHandler
```

Second, you could add the logging.properties location to your pom.xml, like this:

```
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
       <systemProperties>
         <property> 
           <name>java.util.logging.config.file</name>
           <value>src/test/resources/logging.properties</value>
         </property>
       </systemProperties>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Good luck!

Comment: The handlers section was not needed. The surefire plugin configuration is what fixes the problem. Thanks!

Comment: I've tried everything reported in these threads...but I still can't get this incredibly verbose logging turned off (in org.dbunit).  I put the file under /src/test/resources, set the systemProperties value in the plugin configuration...no luck.