# Log level in Jerseys new LoggingFeature

Tags: java, jersey

I am trying to log with Jersey 2.23. Since this version, the class `LoggingFilter` is deprecated, as one can read for example here: https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/logging_chapter.html. So I have to use `LoggingFeature` instead.
What did **not** work was the `register` method of `ResourceConfig` as it is explained in this documentation. But in the end the `property` method worked:

```
client.property(LoggingFeature.LOGGING_FEATURE_LOGGER_LEVEL_SERVER, "WARN");
```

This prints every message as a warning. Unfortunately it is documented nowhere (at least I couldn't find anything) which values are allowed. Obviously it has to be a String, because I get a log message that there is no way to transform the value into a String, when I try anything else than a String. Now I want to log this messages with level TRACE and I can't find a suiting String to achieve this. "TRACE" and "FINE" did not work for example, in these cases nothing is logged. I have to mention that I use Log4j2 together with the Slf4jBridgeHandler because Jersey uses JUL.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I struggled with this myself for several hours before finally uncovering the "mystery" today.

It is somewhat counter-intuitive but the level you are setting with the `LOGGING_FEATURE_LOGGER_LEVEL_SERVER` is actually the minimum level the server's logger must be set to in order to print your logs. I had assumed, based on the name, that this was setting the actual logger level -- implying that setting it to `FINER` or `FINEST` would produce more output. Instead it is simply "turning off" logging unless a specific level is met.

As an example, if you set it to `WARNING` then you will see the logs as long as the server/client is set to print at least `WARNING` level. The levels as defined by java.util.logging are:

> SEVERE (highest value)
>   WARNING
>   INFO
>   CONFIG
>   FINE
>   FINER
>   FINEST (lowest value)

So by setting it to `WARNING` (the literal `WARN` does not work for me in 2.23.1) you will see the logs because, by default, logging is typically at `INFO` level.

An alternate solution is to change the default logging level in your `logging.properties` file which is typically in `$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/logging.properties`. You could, for example, make the following changes to the file and you would no longer need to set any special properties in your code:

```
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = FINEST  
org.glassfish.jersey.test.JerseyTest.level = FINEST
```

The obvious disadvantage to this is that it will effect anything you run from this JDK/JRE. There are ways you can override this standard location and use an alternate `logging.properties` file but it depends on how you're executing your code so I will let you research that based on your circumstances.

One example would be this thread which explains how to do it when using Maven: [Logging level under maven surefire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939072/logging-level-under-maven-surefire)

Comment: Wow, this tripped me up for..I won't admit how long. The default jdk INFO was hiding everything. And as you mentioned, totally counter-intuitive to set the Jersey _SERVER level to WARN or SEVERE