# Hide maven "Running com.MyTest" log line

Tags: maven, maven-surefire-plugin

I get the following in my mvn output:

```
Running com.MyTest
Tests run: 1 , Failures: 0 , Errors: 0 , Skipped: 0 , Time elapsed: 0.02 sec - in com.MyTest
```

despite having the flags:

```
-Dsurefire.printSummary=false -Dsurefire.useFile=true
```

Is there a way to hide the first line - `Running com.MyTest`?

**More information**

It should be irrelevant, but I also add this:

```
-Dlogback.configurationFile=/Users/me/logback.xml
```

with the logback.xml containing:

```
<configuration>
  <root level="OFF">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
  </root>
</configuration>
```

**pom.xml surefire configuration**

```
<project>
  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>${maven.surefire.plugin}</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>

    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${maven.surefire.plugin}</version>
        <configuration>
          <includes>
            <include>**/*Test.class</include>
          </includes>
          <parallel>classes</parallel>
          <threadCount>10</threadCount>
          <useFile>false</useFile>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

    </plugins>
  </build>

  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>coverage-per-test</id>
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.15</version>
            <configuration>
              <properties>
                <property>
                  <name>listener</name>
                  <value>org.sonar.java.jacoco.JUnitListener</value>
                </property>
              </properties>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
</project>
```

Comment: I don't think your logback confg is even used, check out this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/12276898/1743880

Comment: Yeah I know. I just included that so that I don't get replies telling me to configure the log level.

Comment: With this configuration `-Dsurefire.printSummary=false -Dsurefire.useFile=true`, you should not have that line, neither in the console nor in the output file. Just tested with version 2.19.1 of Surefire. Which version of Surefire Plugin are you using?

Comment: `maven.surefire.plugin` = `2.19.1`. Hmmm, this is not the first time I've seen different behavior in my environment compared to the documentation. The previous time there was something overriding it in the pom.xml file (e.g. a profile or goal). So the problem's at my end. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you could post your POM, or the configuration of the Surefire Plugin?

Comment: Updated (with just the relevant parts, I can't post company-specific stuff). Unfortunately there are multiple usages of the plugin so half the battle is figuring out which one is being used (I'm guessing it's just the middle one).

Comment: Correct, it is the middle one that defines `<useFile>false</useFile>`. This takes precedence over what you put on the command line. Set that to `true` and try again.

Comment: Is there a way to override the pom.xml? It seems a bit backwards to me that  the file takes precedence over the command. I don't want to temporarily edit the pom.xml then remember to revert it before merging my code :(

Comment: No, there's no way. But you can set a Maven property. I will write an answer for that.

Comment: I must have the term maven diarrhea in here somewhere to that maven developers take notice. It was removed from the body of my post.

Comment: In all honesty, I removed that, and please do not add it again. It's not constructive and borderline offensive towards the maintainers of the project. If there is something you want improved, feel free to create issues on the JIRA bug tracker, we're looking into them as they come.

Comment: I do not have that much free time on my hands. I'm surprised how no one has ever felt the need to address this. Unix philosophy: Rule of Silence
Developers should design programs so that they do not print unnecessary output. This rule aims to allow other programs and developers to pick out the information they need from a program's output without having to parse verbosity. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_philosophy

Comment: Eh, well that is more of a philosophical discussion :). If you want to get rid of the logs and just have the test output, you could also use the `-q` option, redirect the test output to a file, and read the file. For parsing purposes, this will simpler. You can also set a custom `simplelogger.properties` and control exactly the logs written for Maven globally, take a [look here](https://maven.apache.org/maven-logging.html).

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look. I'm not confident me filing a ticket is going to get this fixed because of the complexity & bureaucracy. And I apologize - I certainly don't mean to offend the developers personally.

Comment: Good criticism is always welcomed :), and thanks for your input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this particular line not to be shown, it is necessary that no console logger should be created. [The code is creating this logger](https://github.com/apache/maven-surefire/blob/surefire-2.19.1/maven-surefire-common/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugin/surefire/StartupReportConfiguration.java#L180-L188) when the following method returns `true`:

> ```
> private boolean shouldReportToConsole()
> {
>     return isUseFile() ? isPrintSummary() : isRedirectTestOutputToFile() || isBriefOrPlainFormat();
> }
> ```

Further down the line, if this returns `true`, an instance of [`ConsoleReporter`](https://github.com/apache/maven-surefire/blob/surefire-2.19.1/maven-surefire-common/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugin/surefire/report/ConsoleReporter.java) [is created](https://github.com/apache/maven-surefire/blob/surefire-2.19.1/maven-surefire-common/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugin/surefire/StartupReportConfiguration.java#L182) and [it will write](https://github.com/apache/maven-surefire/blob/surefire-2.19.1/maven-surefire-common/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugin/surefire/report/ConsoleReporter.java#L96-L99) that line [when the tests are started](https://github.com/apache/maven-surefire/blob/surefire-2.19.1/maven-surefire-common/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugin/surefire/report/TestSetRunListener.java#L114-L117).

So either:

- you set [`useFile=true`](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#useFile) (the default) and [`printSummary=false`](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#printSummary), or
- you set `useFile=false` and [`redirectTestOutputToFile=false`](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#redirectTestOutputToFile) (the default) and [`reportFormat`](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#reportFormat) to a value that isn't `"brief"` or `"plain"` (by default, it is `"brief"`).

As such, with your configuration of `-Dsurefire.printSummary=false -Dsurefire.useFile=true`, it should work, and that line should not be in the console, nor should it be in the output file. Your problem is that the configuration of the `maven-surefire-plugin` sets `<useFile>false</useFile>`. **Any value configured in the POM takes direct predence over what you set on the command-line**. This is to make sure that when the POM defines a value, it cannot be overriden and helps to have reproducible builds.

So what you could do instead is force an incorrect value for the `reportFormat` (which would be neither `"brief"` nor `"plain"`), and you'll notice the `"Running "` line won't be emitted any longer.

That is a bit clunky though. So another solution would be to define a Maven property and override that property on the command-line. In your plugin, have:

```
<useFile>${surefire.plugin.useFile}</useFile>
```

and define a property, which defaults to `false`:

```
<properties>
  <surefire.plugin.useFile>false</surefire.plugin.useFile>
</properties>
```

This way, the build behave the same as before. And when you define `-Dsurefire.plugin.useFile=true`, you'll override the Maven property and this will make sure Surefire boots with `useFile` set to `true`.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explain the underlying factors. So should I deliberately use an invalid value for `reportFormat`? I'm happy to do that, I just hope that a future version of maven doesn't forbid me from doing so.

Comment: @Sridhar-Sarnobat Yes, that is why I think it would be preferable not to do that, and go for the override of a new Maven property solution. It's simpler and documented to work.